# jwt stored in cookie but cannot find in browser developer tool

Tags: reactjs, cookies, jwt, backend

I have no idea why it would not work
I have been trying for entire day

below is my login function

```
    const loginUser = async (req,res) => {
  try {
    const { userName, password } = req.body;
    const foundOne = await User.findOne({ userName : userName }); 
    //sine findOne is for Object so must use key value pair to find

    if (!foundOne) {
      return res.status(400).send("用戶不存在或密碼錯誤");
    }

    const isMatch = await bcrypt.compare(password, foundOne.password);
    if (!isMatch) {
      return res.status(400).send("用戶不存在或密碼錯誤");
    }

    if (foundOne.isVerified !== true) {
      return res.status(400).send("請先驗證電子郵件");
    }
    const payload = { id: foundOne._id,  username: foundOne.userName, role: foundOne.role , isAdmin: foundOne.isAdmin };
    // could be referred to req.body.id in isAdmin
    const JWToken = JWTsign(payload);
    return res.cookie("access_token", JWToken ,{
      httpOnly: true
    }).status(200).json({ message: '登錄成功' });
  } catch (e) {
    return res.status(500).send("登錄錯誤");
  }
};
```

in postman
I can see my jwt in cookies

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yfqwm.png)

however , I cannot see anything in developer tool from brwoser

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bZ844.png)

am I missing something

because when I try to access logout API
I use below function

```
    const logoutUser = async (req,res)=>{
  try{
    console.log(res)
    console.log(res.cookies)
    res
    .clearCookie("access_token")
    .status(200)
    .json({message: "登出成功"})
    console.log(res.cookies)
    
  }catch(e){
    res.status(500).json(e.response)
  }
}
```

and the result of  console.log(res) is

```
cookies: [Object: null prototype] {},
signedCookies: [Object: null prototype] {},
```

does it mean I never send my so-called jwtCookie to frontend ?
or do I need to apply some library to read that jwtCookie and store it in localstorage???

please help please help please help

Comment: in cookie options alongside http property also put maxAge property, it might work